# How do you extend the space (bounds) of a CIImage without stretching the original?

Tags: swift, resize, crop, cifilter, ciimage

I'm applying several filters on an already cropped image, and I'd like a flipped duplicate of it next to the original. This would make it twice as wide.

Problem: How do you extend the bounds so both can fit? .cropped(to:CGRect) will stretch whatever original content was there. The reason there is existing content is because I'm trying to use applyingFilter as much as possible to save on processing. It's also why I'm cropping the original un-mirrored image.

Below is my CIImage "alphaMaskBlend2" with a compositing filter, and a transform applied to the same image that flips it and adjusts its position. sourceCore.extent is the size I want the final image.

```
    alphaMaskBlend2 = alphaMaskBlend2?.applyingFilter("CISourceAtopCompositing",
                                                      parameters: [kCIInputImageKey: (alphaMaskBlend2?.transformed(by: scaledImageTransform))!,
                                                                   kCIInputBackgroundImageKey: alphaMaskBlend2!]).cropped(to: sourceCore.extent)
```

I've played around with the position of the transform in LLDB. I found with this filter being cropped, the left most image becomes stretched. If I use clamped to the same extent, and then I re-crop the image to the same extent again, the image is no longer distorted, but the bounds of the image is only half the width that it should be.

The only way I could achieve this, is compositing against a background image (sourceCore) that would be the size of the two images combined, and then compositing the other image:

```
    alphaMaskBlend2 = alphaMaskBlend2?.applyingFilter("CISourceAtopCompositing",
                                                      parameters: [kCIInputImageKey: alphaMaskBlend2!,
                                                                   kCIInputBackgroundImageKey: sourceCore])

    alphaMaskBlend2 = alphaMaskBlend2?.applyingFilter("CISourceAtopCompositing",
                                                      parameters: [kCIInputImageKey: (alphaMaskBlend2?.cropped(to: cropRect).transformed(by: scaledImageTransform))!,
                                                                   kCIInputBackgroundImageKey: alphaMaskBlend2!])
```

Problem is, that this is more expensive than necessary. I even tested it with benchmarking. It would make a lot more sense if I could do this with one composite.

Comment: If you have little concern about "real-time" adjustments, couldn't you simply write things out through a context and "stitch" the two CIImages together?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned, this is done in real time through the camera.

Comment: I edited the post to show what I'm doing to resolve it, but it's not great for performance and doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: Ow. Not sure how good the performance will be through the camera, but I was just now realizing something I'm currently working through - it uses UIViews to create a mask - might be of help. I may have something that uses the GPU entirely, which is *key* to performance. You can easily "flip" a CIImage by using `CIPerspectiveCorrection`, by "flipping either the X or Y axis. Now the question is how best to "stitch".... If I have something I'll post it today or tomorrow. Maybe if you want to look at something, check out that CIFilter.

Comment: That might help with performance instead of me using a -1 x scale translation, but if you figure out how to stitch them together to make one large image on the GPU, (specifically on a CIImage)  that would be a helpful answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I *can* "flip" a `CIImage` I couldn't find a way to use an existing `CIFilter` to "stitch" it along side the original. However, with some basic knowledge of writing your own `CIKernel`, you can. A simple project of achieving this is [here](https://github.com/justdfd/CIImageStitch).

This project contains a sample image, and using CoreImage and a `GLKView` it:

- flips the image by transposing the Y "bottom/top" coordinates for `CIPerspectiveCorrection`
- creates a new "palette" image using `CIConstantColor` and then crops it using `CICrop` to be twice the width of the original
- uses a very simple CIKernel (registered as "Stitch" to actually stitch it together

**Here's the code to flip:**

```
    // use CIPerspectiveCorrection to "flip" on the Y axis

    let minX:CGFloat = 0
    let maxY:CGFloat = 0
    let maxX = originalImage?.extent.width
    let minY = originalImage?.extent.height

    let flipFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIPerspectiveCorrection")
    flipFilter?.setValue(CIVector(x: minX, y: maxY), forKey: "inputTopLeft")
    flipFilter?.setValue(CIVector(x: maxX!, y: maxY), forKey: "inputTopRight")
    flipFilter?.setValue(CIVector(x: minX, y: minY!), forKey: "inputBottomLeft")
    flipFilter?.setValue(CIVector(x: maxX!, y: minY!), forKey: "inputBottomRight")
    flipFilter?.setValue(originalImage, forKey: "inputImage")
    flippedImage = flipFilter?.outputImage
```

**Here's the code to create the palette:**

```
    let paletteFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIConstantColorGenerator")
    paletteFilter?.setValue(CIColor(red: 0.7, green: 0.4, blue: 0.4), forKey: "inputColor")
    paletteImage = paletteFilter?.outputImage
    let cropFilter = CIFilter(name: "CICrop")
    cropFilter?.setValue(paletteImage, forKey: "inputImage")
    cropFilter?.setValue(CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: (originalImage?.extent.width)! * 2, w: (originalImage?.extent.height)!), forKey: "inputRectangle")
    paletteImage = cropFilter?.outputImage
```

**Here's the code to register and use the custom `CIFilter`:**

```
    // register and use stitch filer

    StitchedFilters.registerFilters()
    let stitchFilter = CIFilter(name: "Stitch")
    stitchFilter?.setValue(originalImage?.extent.width, forKey: "inputThreshold")
    stitchFilter?.setValue(paletteImage, forKey: "inputPalette")
    stitchFilter?.setValue(originalImage, forKey: "inputOriginal")
    stitchFilter?.setValue(flippedImage, forKey: "inputFlipped")
    finalImage = stitchFilter?.outputImage
```

All of this code (long with layout constraints) in the demo project is in `viewDidLoad`, so please, place it where it belongs!

**Here's the code to (a) create a `CIFilter` subclass called Stitch and (b) register it so you can use it like any other filter:**

```
func openKernelFile(_ name:String) -> String {
    let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: ".cikernel")
    do {
        return try String(contentsOfFile: filePath!)
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        return error.description
    }
}

let CategoryStitched = "Stitch"

class StitchedFilters: NSObject, CIFilterConstructor {
    static func registerFilters() {
        CIFilter.registerName(
            "Stitch",
            constructor: StitchedFilters(),
            classAttributes: [
                kCIAttributeFilterCategories: [CategoryStitched]
            ])
    }
    func filter(withName name: String) -> CIFilter? {
        switch name {
        case "Stitch":
            return Stitch()
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}

class Stitch:CIFilter {

    let kernel = CIKernel(source: openKernelFile("Stitch"))
    var inputThreshold:Float  = 0
    var inputPalette: CIImage!
    var inputOriginal: CIImage!
    var inputFlipped: CIImage!

    override var attributes: [String : Any] {
        return [
            kCIAttributeFilterDisplayName: "Stitch",

            "inputThreshold": [kCIAttributeIdentity: 0,
                               kCIAttributeClass: "NSNumber",
                               kCIAttributeDisplayName: "Threshold",
                               kCIAttributeDefault: 0.5,
                               kCIAttributeMin: 0,
                               kCIAttributeSliderMin: 0,
                               kCIAttributeSliderMax: 1,
                               kCIAttributeType: kCIAttributeTypeScalar],

            "inputPalette": [kCIAttributeIdentity: 0,
                             kCIAttributeClass: "CIImage",
                             kCIAttributeDisplayName: "Palette",
                             kCIAttributeType: kCIAttributeTypeImage],

            "inputOriginal": [kCIAttributeIdentity: 0,
                              kCIAttributeClass: "CIImage",
                              kCIAttributeDisplayName: "Original",
                              kCIAttributeType: kCIAttributeTypeImage],

            "inputFlipped": [kCIAttributeIdentity: 0,
                             kCIAttributeClass: "CIImage",
                             kCIAttributeDisplayName: "Flipped",
                             kCIAttributeType: kCIAttributeTypeImage]
        ]
    }
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    override func setValue(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String) {
        switch key {
        case "inputThreshold":
            inputThreshold = value as! Float
        case "inputPalette":
            inputPalette = value as! CIImage
        case "inputOriginal":
            inputOriginal = value as! CIImage
        case "inputFlipped":
            inputFlipped = value as! CIImage
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    @available(*, unavailable) required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    override var  outputImage: CIImage {
        return kernel!.apply(
            extent: inputPalette.extent,
            roiCallback: {(index, rect) in return rect},
            arguments: [
                inputThreshold as Any,
                inputPalette as Any,
                inputOriginal as Any,
                inputFlipped as Any
            ])!
    }
}
```

**Finally, the `CIKernel` code:**

```
kernel vec4 stitch(float threshold, sampler palette, sampler original, sampler flipped) {
    vec2 coord = destCoord();
    if (coord.x < threshold) {
        return sample(original, samplerCoord(original));
    } else {
        vec2 flippedCoord = coord - vec2(threshold, 0.0);
        vec2 flippedCoordinate = samplerTransform(flipped, flippedCoord);
        return sample(flipped, flippedCoordinate);
    }
}
```

Now, someone else may have something more elegant - maybe even using an existing CIFilter - but this works well. It only uses the GPU, so performance-wise, can be used in "real time". I added unneeded code (registering the filter, using a dictionary to define attributes) to make it more of a teaching exercise for those new to creating `CIKernels` that anyone with knowledge of using `CIFilters` can consume. If you focus on the kernel code, you'll recognize how similar to `C` it looks.

Last, a caveat. I am only stitching the (Y-axis) flipped image to the right of the original. You'll need to adjust things if you want something else.

Comment: Thanks for all this effort. It may be because I need to figure out how to achieve this with chaining, but I have about 10-15% more CPU than my other filter. Just curious: What is the pallet filter for exactly? The RGB values look arbitrary, but maybe there's a reason for it. Is it necessary?

Comment: I'm guessing the palette image is just to see if everything is aligned. I removed it from all the code. Curiously, I'm still getting that extra 10-15% processor bump, possibly from not chaining.

Comment: The stitch alone has the bump too - A little less, but still there. If I could combine the two compositing filters, that would free up a good amount of CPU. The main concern for the performance, is that I'm running this through the camera in realtime. Otherwise, it wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Making a long story short, my next app (nearly done) has a "compose" function - starting with a palette (a CIImage) that is 640x640, can have images added to it, along with filters that change the look. I adapted that concept here - you need to do a few things... flip the image, stitch it together, and (in terms of what the palette is for), create a final output that is the height and DOUBLE the width in terms of extent. So that's the only reason for it. Yep, it isn't "elegant" as I said in the answer.

Comment: Having said what the palette is about, here's the rest. I couldn't find a SIMPLE (read: native CI filter way) to both flip an image (you already had that) *and* stitch it. So I created one. One that used a simple use of kernel code. (I'm still hopeful that others better than I have a better way. Several CI filters yield output with "infinite" extents - it's up to *you* to give it one. That, combined with understanding how CI kernels are processed (color versus warp/general) achieved my code. My attempt is more about a static image. I have one last comment....

Comment: I nearly always end up recommending this - and may have already recommended this to you already! Simon Gladman is my main inspiration. This blog article ( http://flexmonkey.blogspot.com/2015/07/applying-cifilters-to-live-camera-feed.html?q=camera ) is old - I think Swift 2 - but still timely. He's moved on to other things. But he is still *the* source for CoreImage as far as I care. His book "CoreImage for Swift" (also Swift 2) is still my "go to" for things. In your case, yes, I checked out if I could use ROI instead of a pretty simple filter. Maybe something there could help you also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179408/discussion-between-chewie-the-chorkie-and-dfd).